# Algunos estilos css para generar un PDF con html-pdf no se respetan en Nginx

Tags: html, css, typescript, pdf, node-html-pdf

Necesito ayuda con un programa de generación de reportes, es una API en DigitalOcean con un servidor nginx. Utilizo pm2 para poder mantener el servicio funcionando en el puerto 3000, de **forma local (Apache con XAMPP); no hay ningún problema con el diseño del reporte**, pero a la hora de ejecutarlo desde nginx, **TODO SE DESCUADRA**.

Tengo **exactamente lo mismo** en el Droplet con nginx que en localhost con XAMPP (*utilizo git para replicarlo*).

Ya intenté: instalar la fuente que se utiliza de forma local, quitar la fuente, mover el css a un archivo aparte, mantenerlo con la etiqueta style dentro del template.html y **nada funciona**.

Aquí mi código de html-pdf: (que no tendría por qué estar mal, ya que en localhost no tiene **ningún problema**)

```
pdf.create(templateHtml, options).toFile('./reports/PES ' + partial + "° parcial - " + semester + group + "-" + period + ".pdf", function (err, file) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        return res.sendFile(path.resolve('reports/PES ' + partial + "° parcial - " + semester + group + "-" + period + ".pdf"));
    });
```

Y una prueba de cómo aparece:

**LOCAL DESDE XAMPP APACHE (ASÍ DEBE VERSE):**
[image: Correcta forma (codigo ejecutado desde XAMPP en localhost)]

**REMOTO (DESCUADRADO, ejecutado desde el droplet con ubuntu y nginx)**
[image: Parece que la fuente y los margenes son lo unico que no se respeta]

También, acabo de percatarme que en APACHE (localhost) existe un margen que no se puede retirar por encima del id #pageHeader; pruebo añadiendo un margin-top: -20px, y aunque el header se corre no se visualiza, como si en la configuración de la página hubiera un margen de impresión (que no lo hay porque ingreso correctamente las options de esta forma):

```
const options: CreateOptions = {
            "format": "Letter",
            "border": "0",
            "orientation": "portrait",
            "header": {
                "height": "50mm",
            },
        }
```

En Nginx (**segunda imagen**), el margen que se aprecia por encima en la **primera imagen (localhost Apache Xampp)** DESAPARECE, por lo que me lleva a pensar que el problema radica en NGINX o APACHE, algo afecta al div id pageHeader y al documento en general. Son EXACTAMENTE los mismos códigos.

Comment: Por lo que parece, o bien el fuente es más grande o bien la página es más pequeña. Juega con los tamaños de la letra con un font-size:80% en la versión del nginx por ejemplo, y ves cambiandolo hasta que se adapte a lo que buscas.  El código que has puesto no es suficiente para ayudarte practicamente en nada más. Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] si quieres mejores respuestas, gracias.

Comment: Gracias y una disculpa por la mala redacción, el estrés que genera este problema es muy agobiante, pero parece que uno de los 2 programas de servidor, (ya sea NGINX o APACHE) tienen que ver con el resultado del reporte y es que de forma local, el reporte que me devuelve tiene unos margenes que no se pueden quitar y en el remoto de Nginx esos margenes no aparecen.

Comment: Segun me parece entender, estas usando esto: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf?activeTab=readme. Entiendo que accedes a ambos lugares desde el mismo navegador (es decir, en el mismo navegador te ocurre eso en dos pestañas distintas, una apuntando al apache y el otro al nginx). Lo digo para descartar ese también.

Comment: Por cierto, en la última frase de esa página dicen esto: `There are more options concerning the paperSize, header & footer options inside the phantomjs script.`... no se exactamente a que se refiere, pero quizas deberias revisar si el phantomjs script ese lo tienes igual de configurado en ambos lugares.

Comment: Accedo desde el mismo navegador, incluso con postman me devuelve el mismo error. Explore ya todas las opciones del phantom.js, se me afiguraba mas a algún tipo de "estilo" o "diseño" preestablecido para html (css) en nginx diferente a apache

Comment: Pues llegado este punto yo lo probaria en otros servidores/maquinas, no solo en esos dos, para ver si consigues reproducir el error también o no. Y sacar más conclusiones.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021547/different-pdf-output-for-windows-and-linux-using-phantomjs-1-9En esta pregunta que hicieron ¡Hace casi 9 años! describe mi problema, lamentablemente las soluciones de establecer el zoomFactor en 0.5 o poner las medidas en mm no me funcionan a mi.

Comment: Creo que eso que dices se define en el phantomJS, y no en el html-pdf... ¿lo has hecho allí?

Answer (score 1):

Phantom js funciona de forma diferente en linux que en windows, principalmente con el tamaño de la fuente y papel. No descubrí una forma para que trabaje igual en ambos sistemas pero pude resolver el problema diseñando los reportes directamente desde ubuntu (instale linux en mi pc) para que a la hora de subirlos sean lo mismo.